почему не выполняется код после выполняния entrypoint.sh nestjs prisma postgresql
у меня Nest JS приложение которое взаимодейтсвует с базой данных PostgreSQL 
и почему то в Dockerfile после файла запуска entrypoint.sh (этот файл я использую для выполнения инициализции и миграции prism'ы в бд ) выполнение Dockerfil'а не идет.
вот мой Docker-compose файл
version: '3.5'

services:
 db:
   image: postgres
   restart: always
   env_file:
     - .env
   environment:
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
     - POSTGRES_HOST=db
   container_name: postgres
   ports:
     - '5432:5432'
 app:
   image: node
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
   container_name: nest-docker-postgres
   entrypoint: ["./entrypoint.sh"]
   environment:
     - PORT=${PORT}
   ports:
     - '3000:3000'
   depends_on:
     - db

Вот мой Dockerfile
FROM node:20

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install NestJS dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory
COPY . .

# Make the entrypoint script executable
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

# Set the entrypoint and default command
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]

а вот мой entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

npx prisma generate

npx prisma migrate dev

exec "$@"

Сижу уже неделю))
Миграции и инициализация успешно выполняется
Вот логи
 => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 811B                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [app internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20                                                                                                                                                              2.5s
 => [app internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 100B                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [app 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:20@sha256:3b676479124ebdb0348f540e5c8b64f959ec1358cea05080b711d965f5353a34                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [app internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 6.62kB                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [app 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [app 3/6] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => CACHED [app 4/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => CACHED [app 5/6] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => CACHED [app 6/6] RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [app] exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                0.1s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => => writing image sha256:da3243300b2333fc58828fa8eabbb787db8d017cf2896d384d2476fa5b5cda8c                                                                                                                                0.1s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/node                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
[+] Running 3/2
 ✔ Network dremin-s-recipes-backend-_default  Created                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 ✔ Container postgres                         Created                                                                                                                                                                      33.1s 
 ✔ Container nest-docker-postgres             Created                                                                                                                                                                       0.1s 
Attaching to nest-docker-postgres, postgres
postgres              | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres              | This user must also own the server process.
postgres              | 
postgres              | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres              | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres              | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres              | 
postgres              | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres              | 
postgres              | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres              | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres              | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres              | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres              | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres              | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgres              | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres              | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgres              | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
nest-docker-postgres  | Environment variables loaded from .env
nest-docker-postgres  | Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
nest-docker-postgres  | 
nest-docker-postgres  | ✔ Generated Prisma Client (v5.10.2) to ./node_modules/@prisma/client in 102ms
nest-docker-postgres  | 
nest-docker-postgres  | Start using Prisma Client in Node.js (See: https://pris.ly/d/client)
nest-docker-postgres  | ```
nest-docker-postgres  | import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
nest-docker-postgres  | const prisma = new PrismaClient()
nest-docker-postgres  | ```
nest-docker-postgres  | or start using Prisma Client at the edge (See: https://pris.ly/d/accelerate)
nest-docker-postgres  | ```
nest-docker-postgres  | import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client/edge'
nest-docker-postgres  | const prisma = new PrismaClient()
nest-docker-postgres  | ```
nest-docker-postgres  | 
nest-docker-postgres  | See other ways of importing Prisma Client: http://pris.ly/d/importing-client
nest-docker-postgres  | 
nest-docker-postgres  | ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
nest-docker-postgres  | │  Deploying your app to serverless or edge functions?        │
nest-docker-postgres  | │  Try Prisma Accelerate for connection pooling and caching.  │
nest-docker-postgres  | │  https://pris.ly/cli/accelerate                             │
nest-docker-postgres  | └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
nest-docker-postgres  | 
postgres              | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres              | 
postgres              | 
postgres              | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres              | 
postgres              |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres              | 
postgres              | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres              | initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres              | waiting for server to start....2024-04-11 11:01:42.073 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.079 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.094 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-04-11 11:01:39 UTC
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.101 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres              |  done
postgres              | server started
postgres              | 
postgres              | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
postgres              | 
postgres              | waiting for server to shut down...2024-04-11 11:01:42.187 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres              | .2024-04-11 11:01:42.194 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.195 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.196 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.201 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.228 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.009 s, sync=0.007 s, total=0.033 s; sync files=2, longest=0.004 s, average=0.004 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB; lsn=0/14EAA70, redo lsn=0/14EAA70
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.232 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres              |  done
postgres              | server stopped
postgres              | 
postgres              | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres              | 
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.310 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.311 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.311 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.319 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.327 UTC [62] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-04-11 11:01:42 UTC
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.334 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
nest-docker-postgres  | Environment variables loaded from .env
nest-docker-postgres  | Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
nest-docker-postgres  | Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "db:5432"
nest-docker-postgres  | 
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.457 UTC [67] ERROR:  relation "_prisma_migrations" does not exist at character 126
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.457 UTC [67] STATEMENT:  SELECT "id", "checksum", "finished_at", "migration_name", "logs", "rolled_back_at", "started_at", "applied_steps_count" FROM "_prisma_migrations" ORDER BY "started_at" ASC
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.692 UTC [68] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.798 UTC [60] LOG:  checkpoint starting: immediate force wait
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:42.852 UTC [60] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 6 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.015 s, sync=0.013 s, total=0.055 s; sync files=5, longest=0.007 s, average=0.003 s; distance=4257 kB, estimate=4257 kB; lsn=0/1913240, redo lsn=0/1913208
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:43.306 UTC [69] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:43.437 UTC [60] LOG:  checkpoint starting: immediate force wait
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:43.533 UTC [60] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 4 buffers (0.0%); 1 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.004 s, sync=0.004 s, total=0.096 s; sync files=4, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4503 kB, estimate=4503 kB; lsn=0/1D78E78, redo lsn=0/1D78E40
nest-docker-postgres  | Applying migration `20240302093845_init`
nest-docker-postgres  | Applying migration `20240302104810_init`
nest-docker-postgres  | Applying migration `20240302110918_init`
nest-docker-postgres  | Applying migration `20240302111059_init`
nest-docker-postgres  | Applying migration `20240303121629_`
nest-docker-postgres  | Applying migration `20240303130206_`
nest-docker-postgres  | Applying migration `20240303143722_`
nest-docker-postgres  | Applying migration `20240303162844_aaaa`
nest-docker-postgres  | Applying migration `20240309100235_`
nest-docker-postgres  | Applying migration `20240312174244_`
nest-docker-postgres  | 
nest-docker-postgres  | The following migration(s) have been applied:
nest-docker-postgres  | 
nest-docker-postgres  | migrations/
nest-docker-postgres  |   └─ 20240302093845_init/
nest-docker-postgres  |     └─ migration.sql
nest-docker-postgres  |   └─ 20240302104810_init/
nest-docker-postgres  |     └─ migration.sql
nest-docker-postgres  |   └─ 20240302110918_init/
nest-docker-postgres  |     └─ migration.sql
nest-docker-postgres  |   └─ 20240302111059_init/
nest-docker-postgres  |     └─ migration.sql
nest-docker-postgres  |   └─ 20240303121629_/
nest-docker-postgres  |     └─ migration.sql
nest-docker-postgres  |   └─ 20240303130206_/
nest-docker-postgres  |     └─ migration.sql
nest-docker-postgres  |   └─ 20240303143722_/
nest-docker-postgres  |     └─ migration.sql
nest-docker-postgres  |   └─ 20240303162844_aaaa/
nest-docker-postgres  |     └─ migration.sql
nest-docker-postgres  |   └─ 20240309100235_/
nest-docker-postgres  |     └─ migration.sql
nest-docker-postgres  |   └─ 20240312174244_/
nest-docker-postgres  |     └─ migration.sql
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:44.051 UTC [70] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:44.153 UTC [60] LOG:  checkpoint starting: immediate force wait
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:01:44.215 UTC [60] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 108 buffers (0.7%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.005 s, sync=0.044 s, total=0.063 s; sync files=103, longest=0.0=103, longest=0.013 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4959 kB, estimate=4959 kB; lsn=0/2250CF8, redo lsn=0/2250CC0
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:06:44.212 UTC [60] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
postgres              | 2024-04-11 11:06:48.949 UTC [60] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 48 buffers (0.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=4.718 s, sync=0.008 s, total=4.737 s; sync files=13, longest=0.004 s, average=0.001 s; distance=276 kB, estimate=4491 kB; lsn=0/2295DD0, redo lsn=0/2295D98
````

